# Compile stylesheet XSL with strange tag <a:tag>

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xslt, xml-parsing

Here is my XML file and method from java:

**test**.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orders>
    <orderDetails>
        <a:orderDetails6>
            <a:MsgId>text1</a:MsgId>
            <a:PartnerId>text1</a:PartnerId>
            <a:OrderId>text1</a:OrderId>                        
        </a:orderDetails6>
    </orderDetails>
</orders>
```

**RX**.java

```
public class RX {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws TransformerException, SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {
        File stylesheet = new File("C:\\style.xsl");
        File xmlSource = new File("C:\\test.xml");

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(xmlSource);

        StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(stylesheet);
                Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(stylesource);

                Source source = new DOMSource(document);

                Result outputTarget = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\x.csv"));
        transformer.transform(source, outputTarget);
    }
}
```

**Style**.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >

<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>A:MsgId,A:PartnerId,A:OrderId
</xsl:text>     
        <xsl:for-each select="//orderDetails">
            <xsl:for-each select="//a:orderDetails6">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(a:MsgId,',',a:PartnerId,',',a:OrderId,'&#xA;')"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If into XML and XLS I have normal tag like:

[MsgID], [PartnerID],[orderDetails6] it's working fine.

But my XML has alwyas tag starting from: [a: ...]

Any idea how to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML input to XSLT needs to be namespace-well-formed. That means that if it uses a qualified name like `<a:orderDetails6>`, the prefix (`a`) needs to be declared in a namespace declaration, for example `xmlns:a="some.uri"`. Technically, your XML conforms with the XML specification but not with the XML namespaces specification, but XSLT (and a lot of other XML processing software) requires conformance with both.

You also need to declare the namespace in your stylesheet. You can't use a path expression like `//a:orderDetails` unless the prefix `a` is declared in a namespace declaration. (Conversely, you don't need the `xmlns:fo` declaration because the prefix `fo` is never used.)

Comment: can you please give me a example how can I correct it

Comment: Correcting it depends on whether there is some specification for the XML vocabulary you are using. If you just made it up and can change it any way you like, the simplest way is to drop the namespace prefixes entirely.

Comment: even tag has prefix, I don't neet to put it into my xsl?